# TestNG, Jenkins, Integrationtesting a RESTful API: how to specify the Base URL?

Tags: java, integration-testing, jenkins, testng

I'm developing a RESTful webservice in Java. For Integrationtesting I use a separate project, which uses the jersey client to access the webservice.

During development I deploy the artifacts on a local glassfish, so the Base URL for the Integrationtests is something like `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApplication/myServlet/`. I run the integration tests from within Netbeans against the local appserver.

I use jenkins to build, deploy and execute the integration tests on the test system. Once deployed on the test system, the Base URL is different, more like this: `https://test.myproduct.com/myProductName/`. Reverse proxies route the traffic to application servers.

Today the URL is a `final static String` in one of the integrationtest classes. How can use get Jenkins (or Netbeans, if that's easier) to provide the Base URL to an integration test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using maven, the natural solution is to use different profiles: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html has a discussion of exactly your problem. In Jenkins you can easily pick the correct profile.

If you are not using maven, the solution is still to not use a hard coded string value, but to pick up the value from an external property.